# How to choose between libxmljs or libxmljs2 for node.js

Tags: node.js, libxml2, libxml-js

What are the current differences or improvements of libxmljs2 vs libxmljs ?
Which one to choose for a new node.js project?
libxmljs seems active again as of today, so the reason of the libxmljs2 fork seems not valid anymore...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.